# Suspend on lid close, even with the option OFF

Tags: 12.04, laptop, power-management, suspend, cinnamon

I've set up a friends laptop with Ubuntu 12.04LTS with the Cinnamon desktop, and I'm having a few issues with the power settings.

As far as I can tell I've got every setting to "Do Nothing" when the lid is closed, however it still Suspends when I close the lid.
After much Googling I'm still no closer to a solution, so I came here for help.

Comment: Could you add the laptop brand/model? Most hardware switches are manufacturer specific.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `logind.conf` - this should not disable suspend,  it should just to tell it to ignore the lid switch.

This will also override any of your user's power settings, and will work whether you are logged in or not (system-wide). You can configure it via running:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

You should like something like this:
[image]

Change `HandleLidSwitch=` line to this (with no `#` at the beginning - a `#` at the beginning of the line means it is a comment and will be ignored and the defaults will be used):

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Here is a quote from a manual page  - note it can take other values like `lock`, `poweroff` etc.

> HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=,
>   HandleLidSwitch=
>
> Controls whether logind shall handle the system power and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off or
>   suspend. Can be one of *"ignore"*, *"poweroff"*, *"reboot"*, *"halt"*,
>   *"kexec"*, *"suspend"*, *"hibernate"*, *"hybrid-sleep"* and *"lock"*. If
>   *"ignore"*, logind will never handle these keys. If *"lock"*, all running
>   sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will
>   be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the
>   *"power-switch"* udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.
>   `HandlePowerKey=` defaults to *"poweroff"*. **`HandleSuspendKey=` and
>   `HandleLidSwitch=` defaults to *"suspend"***. `HandleHibernateKey=` defaults to
>   *"hibernate"*.

The manual page for logind is [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#HandlePowerKey=)

Comment: When typing that command in Terminal I get this message;

nano/etc/systemd/logind.conf: command not found

Comment: You need a space after `nano` :-) - you need to copy it exactly. If you still get that error, run this command first `sudo apt-get install nano`.

Comment: Got it to show up now. However as I'm new to Linux I'm not entirely sure I've got the right thing as there's no text to edit... It's just a blank screen.

Comment: If it says 'New file' at the bottom, you have - added screenshot.

Comment: Honestly no idea what I'm doing here :-/
I get this page http://i62.tinypic.com/2h4b8n8.png

Comment: Ok... try `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Comment: Totally blank document as well... frustrating.

Comment: Try adding in the line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`, saving it and closing it... the file should exist :-S - make sure you use the `sudo` bit at the beginning.

Comment: That's now the only text in that document when I re-open it.

Comment: Hopefully the changes should take effect if you reboot.

Comment: Rebooted, and it still Suspends on the lid closing :-(