# Closing a laptop top and keeping ubuntu running

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Edge E130 and a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. If I close the top the OS is sent to sleep mode. I would like to keep Ubuntu running. What exactly is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: I answered [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/425020/178596) a while ago, which might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that newer Lenovo laptops have a lid switch.  By default, the computer goes into suspend when you close the lid, and wakes up when you open it.  My T440p, for example, doesn't have a keyboard "sleep" switch.

This answer is unique to 14.04.  My older 12.04 setup was different (and more difficult to modify).

Open the "Power" settings by clicking on Unity gear icon at upper right hand side of display, then on "System Settings...", wait for the window to open, then click on "Power".  There are option pull-downs to select what happens "when the lid is closed."

I've set my "when the lid is closed" options to "do nothing" for both "on battery power" and "when plugged in" settings.  This inhibits the suspend action, but it nevertheless locks the screen, which you can see if you use your laptop with an external monitor.

It would, of course, be nice if it were possible to select whether the screen locks upon closing the lid, but that option isn't offered yet.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. BTW: In German Power is translated as "Leistung" which is not a very good translation. Something like "Energieverwaltung" or "Energie" would make much more sense.