# Separate options to suspend when on battery power or plugged in

Tags: suspend, 17.10

The power category in GNOME Tweaks only show a "suspend when laptop lid is closed". However, there is no distinction between whether the laptop is plugged (for instance to a docking station or a charger) or operating on battery power.

In my case, I would like my laptop to suspend when closing the lid on battery power, but leave it when plugged to its charger. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this using `dconf-editor`.

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Go to `org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > power`

You will be able to choose separate actions for **lid-close-ac-action** and **lid-close-battery-action**

Comment: This didn't work for me in 17.10, I set lid-close-ac-action to 'blank' but the machine still suspends when the lid is closed while powered.

Comment: May be you should reboot and then check

Comment: @freddybob, If it does not work, then you should try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/425032/574724

Comment: thanks that worked (although, of course, now it does not suspend when the lid is closed whether or not it is plugged in).