# Enable wifi in sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, python

I have a python selenium script which runs for about 1 hour continuously when issued. The problem is that it continously require an internet connection as well. So, when I close my laptop lid, the wifi gets disconnected. I want that even if I close the lid, the wifi must work continously and the script as well.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: May killing suspend and lid close events from system settings would help?

Comment: You'll also need the cpu and disk to be running - which sounds a lot like you don't want it to sleep at all - you want it to run with the lid closed.

Comment: Yes, I want the system to work normally with laptop's lid closed, with wifi working. Any way to do that?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma follow this answer and set the option to **DO NOTHING** when lid is closed https://askubuntu.com/a/968892/574724