# How to set the close-laptop-lid-action?

Tags: 17.10, systemd, standby, systemd-logind

In Ubuntu versions before Gnome Shell, I could set what I wanted to happen when I close the laptop lid depending on whether the laptop is connected to power or not.

Now the default is standby which I can disable in Gnome Tweak Tool. My preferred setting is to only go to standby when on battery and stay on when connected to AC.

Using systemd I only know of options to completely enable or disable lid-actions alltogether. How did Unity solve this in Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: Simply doing [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/968892/480481) will not work, will it?

Comment: @pomsky: nope, those settings are now ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be bug in the [gnome-settings-daemon](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1722286).

A workaround has been proposed by [Kim Nguyễn](https://launchpad.net/~kim.nguyen) in the form of a python script, [custom_suspend.py](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1722286/+attachment/4970889/+files/custom_suspend.py). He/she says:

> The script should be launched as: `systemd-inhibit --who=me
>   --why=because --mode=block --what=handle-lid-switch /path/to/custom_suspend.py`
>
> from the session startup (gnome-session-properties)
>
> This is public domain and only lightly tested. It relies on existing
>   gnome/systemd commands to perform the underlying action

Comment: Hey. I'm not looking to ignore the lidswitch, I want it to only put the laptop in standby, when it's running on battery.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.  It appears to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1722286  There is a workaround proposed in the comments.

Comment: Great find! I'll accept your answer if you update it with the workaround from the bugfix.

Comment: Thanks.. I think you can savely remove the original answer.  It's already available somewhere else and your revised answer does answer the question!

Comment: I added [a comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1722286/comments/5) to the launchpad issue. It seems there is no upstream issue filed.