# How to Prevent Ubuntu from sleeping when Closing Lid

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, lid

I want to prevent my system (Ubuntu 22.04 on old HP laptop) from sleeping when closing the lid.

I already tried to edit my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` :

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#UserStopDelaySec=10
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore                 #
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore    #
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore           #
#HandleRebootKey=reboot
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no            #
#RebootKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
IdleAction=ignore                      #
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RuntimeDirectoryInodesMax=400k
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Before editing, my system slept as soon as the lid was closed; but now it takes a while before sleeping.
The odd thing is that when the lid isn't closed, the system stays awake as long as I want it to.

I don't know if any logs are going to be useful; or what the cause may be.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
suspend
```

And

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action
suspend
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981524/how-to-set-the-close-laptop-lid-action). Did you already try Gnome Tweaks > General > Suspend when laptop lid is closed? What's the output of: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action` and `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action`?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did already edit Gnome tweaks. I edited the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the laptop keep on running after closing the lid run these following commands on the Terminal,

While on AC;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
```

While on Battery;

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work in my case (also on Ubuntu 22.04).
I had to install GNOME Tweaks, which is available on the `universe` repository:

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and disable *Suspend when laptop lid is closed*.

Comment: This only prevents suspend when I'm logged in. My laptop still goes to sleep if I close lid on the login page.