# Ubuntu 18.04 suspends every 10 seconds

Tags: 18.04, suspend

i installed ubuntu 18.04 on my notebook and when i login my screen goes black after about 10 seconds and i have to login again.
I updated everything after installation and tried to upgrade to kernel version 4.17.8.
But i have still the same issue.
Could you help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling "Suspend on lid close" in gnome tweaks does help when you are logged in already.

But if you also have this problem during boot, you have to disable it system-wide. You can find how to do that in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/425032/603556

Comment: Its a workaround though will it get fixed?

Comment: Another option would be to try different kernel versions (e.g. for my laptop this problem occurs on 4.18 but does not on 4.15), but this kinda feels like just another kind of a workaround, so hopefully it will be fixed some day.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself:
I installed gnome tweaks and go to Power -> Suspend when lid is closed uncheck that.